# copying xml file while its open in Java

Tags: java, xml, jdbc-odbc

I am connecting XML with odbc:jdbc from java and updating A.xml file.
After the updating is done, I am copying A.xml to different location and renaming that file(lets say copy.xml).
Everything works fine.
But I noticed that if the original A.xml file has been opened during the time of update, the copy.xml file is empty. 
Then I decided to write a macro in the A.xml file to auto save the worksheet if any column value changes. This macro works, but 
the copy.xml file is still empty.

I am using

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            command.add("cmd.exe");
            command.add("/c");
            command.add("copy A.xml copy.xml ");            
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

to copy file.

Is there a different way to accomplish this.

Comment: While using an external process for this is *generally the wrong approach*, the only reason why `copy.xml` should be empty is if `A.xml` is empty *at the time it was read*. If there was an error reading `A.xml` (e.g. an exclusive file lock) then the new file should not have been created at all: that is, I believe `A.xml` has been truncated (as part of the write?) and the data-source has not written the data back to the disk yet. It sounds like a funky synchronization issue.

Comment: ...or I could be wrong and `copy` is leaving a residue file if `A.xml` is [already] opened [exclusively] and the read fails. Check the process exit code to see if there was an error.

Comment: process.waitFor() is returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can copy a file using Java IO API:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Full documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)
Also, you have to make sure the file is not being updated when you copy it over to the new place.

Comment: Yes (+1), but this doesn't explain why `copy` would result a new *empty* file.

Comment: Multiple readers can read a file simultaneously but access to the same file become exclusive if there is a writer. In your case, you are probably trying to copy (read) the source file where there it is being updated (written into). Who is updating the file? Is it your code or separate thread/process?

Comment: Ok, do you do it in the same thread? Are you sure you are properly closing the file before making a copy of it? If in doubts, please post the code updating this file.